# What can explain heap corruption on a call to free()?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, openssl

I have been debugging a crash for days now, that occurs in the depths of OpenSSL (discussion with the maintainers [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg38571.html)). I took some time investigating so I'll try to make this question interesting and informative.

First and to give some context, my minimal-sample that reproduces the crash is as follow:

```
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/objects.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>

int main()
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings(); OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); 
    ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();

    EC_GROUP* group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_sect571k1);
    EC_GROUP_set_point_conversion_form(group, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED);
    EC_KEY* eckey = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, group);
    EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
    BIO* out = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    BIO_set_fp(out, stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey(out, eckey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL); // <= CRASH.
}
```

Basically, this code generates an Elliptic Curve key and tries to output it to `stdout`. Similar code can be found in `openssl.exe ecparam` and on Wikis online. It works fine on Linux (valgrind reports no error at all). **It only crashes on Windows (Visual Studio 2013 - x64).** I made sure the proper runtimes were linked-to (`/MD` in my case, for all dependencies).

Fearing no evil, I recompiled OpenSSL in x64-debug (this time linking everything in `/MDd`), and stepped through the code to find the offending set of instructions. My search led me to this code (in OpenSSL's `tasn_fre.c` file):

```
static void asn1_item_combine_free(ASN1_VALUE **pval, const ASN1_ITEM *it, int combine)
{
    // ... some code, not really relevant.
    tt = it->templates + it->tcount - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < it->tcount; tt--, i++) {
        ASN1_VALUE **pseqval;
        seqtt = asn1_do_adb(pval, tt, 0);
        if (!seqtt) continue;

        pseqval = asn1_get_field_ptr(pval, seqtt);
        ASN1_template_free(pseqval, seqtt);
    }
    if (asn1_cb)
        asn1_cb(ASN1_OP_FREE_POST, pval, it, NULL);
    if (!combine) {
        OPENSSL_free(*pval); // <= CRASH OCCURS ON free()
        *pval = NULL;
    }
    // Some more code...
}
```

For those not too familiar with OpenSSL and it's ASN.1 routines, basically what this `for`-loop does is that it goes trough all the elements of a sequence (starting with the last element) and "deletes" them (more on that later).

Right before the crash happens, a sequence of 3 elements is deleted (at `*pval`, which is `0x00000053379575E0`). Looking at the memory, one can see the following things happen:

[image: memory dump #1]

The sequence is 12 bytes long, each element being 4-bytes long (in this case, `2`, `5`, and `10`). On each loop iteration, elements are "deleted" by OpenSSL (in this context, neither `delete` or `free` are called: they are just set to a specific value). Here is how the memory looks after one iteration:

[image: memory dump #2]

The last element here was set to `ff ff ff 7f` which I assume is OpenSSL's way of ensuring no key information leaks when the memory is unallocated later.

Right after the loop (and before the call to `OPENSSL_free()`), the memory is as follow:

[image: memory dump #3]

All elements were set to `ff ff ff 7f`, `asn1_cb` is `NULL` so no call is made. The next thing that goes on is the call to `OPENSSL_free(*pval)`.

This call to `free()` on what seems to be a valid & allocated memory fails and cause the execution to abort with a message: **"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED"**.

Curious about this, I hooked into `malloc`, `realloc` and `free` (as OpenSSL permits) to ensure this wasn't a double-free or a free on never-allocated memory. It turns out the memory at `0x00000053379575E0` really is a 12 bytes block that was indeed allocated (and never freed before).

I'm at loss figuring out what happens here: from my research, it seems that `free()` fails on a pointer that was normally returned by `malloc()`. In addition to that, this memory location was being written to a couple of instructions before without any problem which confirms the hypothesis that the memory be correctly allocated.

I know it's hard, if not impossible, to debug remotely without all the information but I have no idea what my next steps should be.

So my question is: how exactly is this "HEAP CORRUPTION" detected by Visual Studio's debugger ? What are all the possible causes for it when originating from a call to `free()` ?

Comment: You get the error when the runtime detects the issue, but that does not mean that the foul code is in that particular location. You need to verify whether some previous code is releasing memory and later using the pointer to write, which would be my first guess.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's interesting. Would you have any information about how exactly such a check is made ? I'd like to limit the scope of my search. Can I assume that everytime `free()` is called previous writes are checked ?

Comment: Another possibility is that you stumble over the debug library patterns written to allocated/freed locations in order to detect certain errors. If openssl writes some funny values, the debug runtime might conclude memory corruption where there is none. Not likely but possible.

Comment: @user2225104 There is indeed a `fdfdfdfd` value right before the allocated memory (which I believe is a being/end marker used for heap-allocated memory in debug). However, I also assume that such a marker should be present anyway since the memory was indeed allocated.

Comment: @ereOn: I don't really know, I am not a windows developer but a few weeks back I run into a write through a dangling pointer triggering this all over the place (the error was randomly detected in some later allocation/deallocation). Fun.

Comment: The fact that it only crashes on Windows doesn't mean that the error doesn't exist on other platforms. Use `valgrind` or similar to check all memory accesses.

Comment: What's weird here is that the `fdfdfdfd` is the "no-mans-land" data before the memory block allocated, but there should be another `fdfdfdfd` portion right after the memory too ([according to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx)), which doesn't seem to appear in what you've posted. There seems to be `00000000` right after your 12 bytes of data, which would suggest that it has been overwritten, which is why you get the error (the debug heap checks that trailing no-mans-land and detects that an illegal access has happened sometime in the past).

Comment: Include the version of OpenSSL you are using (and mention if it has any custom modifications you made) so that others can try to reproduce

Comment: the OpenSSL devs don't give two tosses about Windows either so you are probably on your own in fixing it!

Comment: @JensGustedt I actually already ran it through `valgrind` (as I state in the question, but it's easy to overlook) and no error showed up.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Latest 1.0.2a release compiled locally (no patches/modifications whatsoever).

Comment: @Matt McNabb this is exactly why I usually avoid to use unix-driven open source libs on windows.

Comment: Another esoteric difference between x64 linux and x64 windows is the different x64 memory models both operating systems use. It would take some dirty code in openssl to reveal that difference, though. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly for further information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general the possibilities include:

1. Duplicate free.
2. *Prior* duplicate free.
3. (Most probable) Your code wrote beyond the limits of the allocated chunk of memory, either before the beginning or after the end. `malloc()` and friends put extra bookkeeping information in here, such as the size, and probably a sanity-check, which you will fail by overwriting.
4. Freeing something that hadn't been `malloc()`-ed.
5. Continuing to write to a chunk that had already been `free()`-d.

Comment: From my question:

"Curious about this, I hooked into malloc, realloc and free (as OpenSSL permits) to ensure this wasn't a double-free or a free on never-allocated memory. It turns out the memory at 0x00000053379575E0 really is a 12 bytes block that was indeed allocated (and never freed before)."

So I'd rule out the first 2 candidates as well.

Comment: @ereOn You can't rule out a prior duplicate `free(),` and your question doesn't suggest that any possibilities should be left out of answers. My concern with this answer would be that I've probably left one or more things out, as I haven't had to deal with this problem for about 18 years.

Comment: Note that Microsoft provides code for the debug CRT (in particular `dbgheap.c`), so you can actually set a breakpoint on all the checks.

Comment: @EJP: I'm not sure why I can't rule out double-frees when I provided my own `free`, `malloc` and `realloc` functions and tracked allocations/deallocations manually (to detect double-frees or invalid frees). Am I missing something ?

Comment: @ereOn *You* can rule out anything you like. *I* can't, for a proper SO answer that starts 'in general'.

Comment: @EJP What time is it ? "In general, it's between 0:00 and 23:59". You can see how giving a general answer to a specific question isn't as helpful as one would think. Even though, I accepted your answer, asked for precisions: not sure why you felt that tone was necessary - **two years after the fact**.

Comment: @ereOn 'Truth isn't a function of time, or a function of the questioner's expectations, and 'tone' is entirely in the eyes of the beholder. There is no way to win answering SO questions, or Internet questions in general: you provide an explaination, they ask for code; you provide code, they ask for an explanation; you give all the reasons, as here, and they ask for only one; you give only one, they ask for them all. I've done my best here, and I have nothing to add or retract. Try educating people yourself some time. You might find it a bit more difficult than you expect.

Comment: That's a very useful answer albeit general!

Answer (score 4):

I could finally find the problem and solve it.

Turned out some instruction was writing bytes past the allocated heap buffer (hence the `0x00000000` instead of the expected `0xfdfdfdfd`).

In debug mode this overwrite of the memory guards remains undetected until the memory is freed with `free()` or reallocated with `realloc()`. This is what caused the **HEAP CORRUPTION** message I faced.

I expect that in release mode, this could have had dramatic effects, like overwritting a valid memory block used somewhere else in the application.

---

For future reference to people facing similar issues, here is how I did:

OpenSSL provides a `CRYPTO_set_mem_ex_functions()` function, defined like so:

```
int CRYPTO_set_mem_ex_functions(void *(*m) (size_t, const char *, int),
                                void *(*r) (void *, size_t, const char *,
                                            int), void (*f) (void *))
```

This function allows you to hook in and replace memory allocation/freeing functions within OpenSSL. The nice thing is the addition of the `const char *, int` parameters which are basically filled for you by OpenSSL and contain the **filename** and **line number** of the allocation.

Armed with this information, it was easy to find out the place where the memory block was allocated. I could then step through the code while looking at the memory inspector waiting for the memory block to be corrupted.

In my case what happenned was:

```
if (!combine) {
    *pval = OPENSSL_malloc(it->size); // <== The allocation is here.

    if (!*pval) goto memerr;

    memset(*pval, 0, it->size);
    asn1_do_lock(pval, 0, it);
    asn1_enc_init(pval, it);
}
for (i = 0, tt = it->templates; i < it->tcount; tt++, i++) {
    pseqval = asn1_get_field_ptr(pval, tt);

    if (!ASN1_template_new(pseqval, tt))
        goto memerr;
}
```

`ASN1_template_new()` is called on the 3 sequence elements to initialize them.

Turns out `ASN1_template_new()` calls in turn `asn1_item_ex_combine_new()` which does this:

```
if (!combine)
    *pval = NULL;
```

`pval` being a `ASN1_VALUE**`, this instruction sets 8 bytes on Windows x64 systems instead of the intended 4 bytes, leading to memory corruption for the last element of the list.

For the full discussion on how this problem was solved upstream, see [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg38571.html).